# How print("YNEOS"[(w%2)|(w<=2)::2]) works

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

I was just trying to solve [this problem on Codeforces](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/4/A): Check whether it's posible to split a number w (1 ≤ w ≤ 100) into a sum of 2 even numbers

I solved the problem and started to look others solutions for the problem. The I found that solution:

```
w=int(input())
print("YNEOS"[(w%2)|(w<=2)::2])
```

it took half of time to solve the problem then mine. Unfortunately I am not getting how it is working and why it is faster than mine. My solution is :

```
n = int(input())
if (n-2)%2==0 and n > 2:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

I am a beginner in python. So it will be very helpful for me it i get a proper explanation.

Comment: questions should be self-contained because people don't want to click on an external link, and that also avoids issues when the external link rots

Answer (score 1):

The `::` part is called [slicing](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings#string-slices). The general syntax is `start:stop[:step]` which will make a new array or string from the original one, beginning from index `start` to *before* `stop` every `step` (default = 1). It's essentially a syntactic sugar for `slice(start, stop, step)` which returns a [slice object](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice). If `stop` is omitted then all the elements till the end of the string will be extracted

- [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/995714)
- [How do I use the slice notation in Python?](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/how-do-i-use-the-slice-notation-in-python)
- https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html

You may want to read [An Informal Introduction to Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html) for more information about slicing

---

Now `(w%2)|(w<=2)` calculates the start index. `|` is the [bitwise-OR operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators). `w<=2` is a bool expression, but in Python [*"Booleans are a subtype of integers"*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex), so True and False will be converted to 1 and 0 respectively

- If w is an **odd** number then `w % 2 == 1`. Regardless of the remaining part, `(w%2)|(w<=2)` will always be 1 in this case and the expression becomes `"YNEOS"[1::2]` which takes every second letter in the string starting from index 1. The result is the string `NO`
- If w is an **even** number then `w % 2 == 0`. According to the problem description `1 ≤ w ≤ 100` the only valid even numbers belong to the range [2, 100]

  - If `w == 2` then `w <= 2` returns 1 and the output is `NO` like above
  - If `w > 2` then both the sides of `(w%2)|(w<=2)` is 0, and `"YNEOS"[0::2]` takes the 1st, 3rd and 5th letters which is `YES`

Realizing that the expression always returns 0 or 1 we'll have an alternative more readable solution that uses direct addressing instead of slicing

```
w=int(input())
print(['YES', 'NO'][(w % 2) | (w <= 2)])
```

Btw, you have a redundant subtraction: `(n-2)%2==0` is exactly the same as `n % 2 == 0`